# Better format to develop a vertical tab plugin?

Tags: jquery

I was trying to develop the vertical tabs plug-in with jQuery, just to learn. I came across a couple of examples, one of jQuery's own and one other plug-in. They implement the **tabs** using unordered lists and the content using **div** elements. In case, although I do not see a reason to why this should happen, javascript is not working or not enabled, they will look like a bunch of list items followed by random unrelated content.

Since I'm just learning, I intuitively did this simple mark-up:

```
<ul id="vTabs">
    <li id="tabs">
        <div id="tab_1">Show 1</div>
             <div id="tab_2">Show 2</div>
    </li>
    <li id="content">
        <div id="content_1">this is data div 1</div>
        <div id="content_2">this is data div 2</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could someone please guide me by telling if this is bad or okay or good? Shall I proceed with this hands-on?

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by VERTICAL tabs. do these tabs run vertically (one under the other) and the content appear at the side, or do they run horizontally (each next to one another in a single line) and the content appear underneath? P.S. do not use numerical IDs, use something like: id="C1" ... not id="1" ...

Comment: Also, ID's have to be unique. You cannot have two or more elements on your page with the same ID.

Comment: Please pardon me for the improper _id_ values. The mark-up is there just for sample. The emphasis here was on the content structure. By _vertical_ tabs, I mean your first definition, tabs running vertically and content besides them.

Answer (score 0):

There should never be 2 elements on a page that have the same ID, as is the case in your structure.

Is there a reason you aren't going with what you've already found? Tabs as list items linked to div elements using the id attribute? Something like this is fairly flexible:

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href="#panel_1">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#panel_2">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#panel_3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="panels">
  <div id="panel_1" class="panel">Foo</div>
  <div id="panel_2" class="panel">Bar</div>
  <div id="panel_3" class="panel">Hi</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Simshaun. Yes, that's the traditional thing I've seen for horizontal tabs. But as I said, _just in case_ JS is not working or disabled, the mark-up will come formatted simple, with the help of supporting CSS. With this structure, wouldn't the content lose its meaning? Just wondering

Comment: Define what you mean by "lose its meaning". If you are talking about "visitor wont know what this content is for", you could put headlines inside each panel and hide them with JS to retain some semblance of structure if JS is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are doing this as an exercise to learn jQuery.

At its simplest the process to follow is:

Using the HTML layout suggested by Simshaun you would float the "panels" DIV (with all the individual "panel" DIVs hidden) to the right of the "tabs" UL and set a "click" handler on the "A" tabs to animate the width of the chosen "panel" DIV.

Once you've got that working, you could make it look fancier, by styling it better with CSS.

Regards
       Neil

Comment: Thank you Neil :) Yes, I am trying it for my interest, I don't need it anywhere though. I understand the logic. However, I wanted to know if the structure I thought of was any good. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Good luck. I got into jQuery a couple of years ago and am always amazed at how easy it is to produce fairly complex web pages using it.